# HTML/CSS vertically shift only some of the text in a paragraph/header

Tags: html, css

What I want to do here is move only part of my heading text upwards, **NOT THE ENTIRE PARAGRAPH/HEADING**, and I want both to be on the same line (or at least appear to be).

What I have is this.

[image]

What I want is this(Note that only "The" has moved up).
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
<h1>
    <a href="index.php"><span style="font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold;margin-top:-15px;"><b>T</b>he</span><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">H</span>allowed <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">H</span>og</a>
</h1>
```

Note how "margin-top:-15px;" does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Gotta say thanks for the insanely quick response!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and the comment... you just witnessed tactical voting ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, though you will need to tweak the vertical-align:

```css
a { text-decoration: none; color: gray }
.the {  font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold;  vertical-align: 17%; }
.rest { font-size: xx-large; }
.rest b { color: red; }
```

```html
<h1>
    <a href="index.php">
      <span class='the'><b>T</b>he</span>
      <span class='rest'><b>H</b>allowed <b>H</b>og</span>
    </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Although all answers given were correct, yours was the clearest

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use the `<sup>` tag (stands for 'superscript').

If this doesn't work, then try applying styles to the `<sup>` tag to get the desired result:

http://jsfiddle.net/d27sf31c/

In this fiddle, I changed the default `<sup>` styling:

`vertical-align:super`

to

`vertical-align:text-top`

This will apply to all `<sup>` tags so on a live site, I'd create a class for the specific section you'd like to apply this style to instead of polluting all `<sup>` tags with the custom style.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote, answer was helpful and well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Using negative `margin-top` you're just altering the inline context of an `inline` span > resulting in no movement

Use:

```
vertical-align
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align > Look at any value type you can use

**Example**:

```css
.red{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}

.the{
  font-size:x-large;
  vertical-align: 20px;    /* ....just use it....*/
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <a href="index.php">
      <span class="the"><b>T</b>he</span><span class="red">H</span>allowed <span class="red">H</span>og
  </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example showing how vertical align can solve this particular problem? Saying "use vertical-align" doesn't really answer the question; the use of `vertical-align` is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add something such as a trademark symbol to your text, but finding it's not small enough or positioned well, you can do something like this:

```
.site-title::after {
    content: "™";
    vertical-align: 120%;
    font-size: .3em !important;
}
```